# Combine xargs argument with some text

Tags: wget, xargs

How can I use `xargs` to pass an argument through to `wget`, but also add some text to that argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need the `-i` option.

e.g.

`echo world | xargs -i echo hello{}`

This will output `helloworld` (no space). The `{}` is replaced with the value, instead of the value being added to the end, as a separate argument.